# Couldn't connect to Docker daemon on ubuntu

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose-version 1.7.0,
Not using docker machine:
`$  docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE   URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS`
it all worked perfectly for weeks...
Now when i try running
`docker-compose up`
i get this error:
`Couldn't connect to Docker daemon-you might need to run docker-machine start default`.
I cant figure out what happened, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Run it with sudo. 
Its bad to run docker with sudo so you should add your user to the docker group
https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo